# Terraform - Azure | Installing Azure Monitor Agent on Linux VM without internet connectivity

Tags: azure, terraform

Considering that the Log Analytics agent will be retired on August 31, 2024, to monitor the instances in my Azure infrastructure, I need to use the new Azure Monitor Agent.
To provide a bit of context, my instances are part of instance sets. Some belong to an Availability Set, and others to a Scale Set.
In the case of the Availability Set, my intention is to install the extension by iterating through each machine in a Terraform loop.

```
# Install Azure Monitor Agent extension in every availability set virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ama_extension" {
  for_each            = var.virtual_machine_ids
  name                = "${each.key}-monitor"
  virtual_machine_id  = each.value
  publisher           = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
  type                = "MonitorX64Linux"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "workspaceId": "${azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics_workspace["common"].id}"
  }
  SETTINGS
}
```

In the case of the Scale Set, the solution appears to be simpler, as it has a parameter related to extensions, and the installation is done as follows:

```
# Flexible scale set:
resource "azurerm_orchestrated_virtual_machine_scale_set" "scale_sets" {
  for_each                    = var.scale_sets
  name                        = "${var.branch_prefix}${var.environment}-${each.value.short_name}-${var.working_area}-ssapp"
  location                    = var.resource_group.rg_location
  resource_group_name         = var.resource_group.rg_name
  platform_fault_domain_count = each.value.platform_fault_domain_count
  sku_name                    = each.value.scale_set_sku
  instances                   = each.value.scale_set_instances

  # Otras configuraciones como networking, instancias, etc.
  network_interface {
    name    = "nic_${each.value.sc_set_index}"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name                                   = "internal"
      primary                                = true
      subnet_id                              = var.subnets_map["${each.value.scale_set_vnet_name}-${each.value.scale_set_subnet_name}"].subnet_id
      load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.internal_lb_pool[each.key].id]
    }
  }

  extension {
    name                                = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
    publisher                           = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
    type                                = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
    type_handler_version                = "1.0"
    auto_upgrade_minor_version_enabled  = true
  }

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.user_identity[each.key].id]
  }


  # Other resource parameters …
}
```

The problem is that, as you can see in the configuration of the scale set, in both cases, I am only connecting the instances to a subnet, leaving them without internet access due to policies I must adhere to. This results in the following error when attempting to install the extensions:
"Enable failed with exit code 53 Installation failed due to incorrect workspace key. Please check if the workspace key is correct. For details, check logs in /var/log/azure/Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.OmsAgentForLinux/extension.log"
Even though the workspace ID is correct, it's causing the extension not to provision.

In this thread: [https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/issues/1266](https://stackoverflow.com), I've seen that they have the same issue, but they solve it by enabling internet connectivity, which I cannot do.

Browsing the internet, I have not found any way to install this Azure Monitor Agent without internet connectivity, but I believe it could be done with the Log Analytics extension
Is there any way I can resolve this by enabling internet connectivity from the instances?
Thank you in advance.

Browsing the internet, I have not found any way to install this Azure Monitor Agent without internet connectivity, but I believe it could be done with the Log Analytics extension.

I need to find the way to install and use this extension without internet connection.